# How to securely compile and hide Clojure code?

Tags: clojure, compilation, executable-jar

Is there a way to securely ship Clojure written code without(or minimizing) the risk of it being decompiled and accessed?

Are jar files generated with uberjar, safe enough to pass around?

Thanks heaps!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281365/obfuscating-clojure-uberjars-with-proguard

Answer (score 1):

If you can run code on a web server that is only accessed over a network by those who use your code, then as long as you keep that server secure, it does not matter whether the server has the source code or not.

It is possible to create JAR files that contain Clojure source code that can be deployed, by using the Clojure compiler on the computer where the JAR is deployed to compile the Clojure source to JVM byte code soon after the JVM process starts.  You can do 'unzip -v foo.jar' on a JAR file to see a list of the file names within it, and any that have a file name suffix like '.clj', '.cljs', or '.cljc' are likely Clojure source code.

If any files in the JAR have file names ending in '.class', those are Java class files containing JVM byte code.  You can run a decompiler on most such files and often get back syntactically legal Java source code that behaves the same as the Clojure source code does.  e.g. See https://github.com/clojure-goes-fast/clj-java-decompiler or do a Google search for 'java decompiler' for many other such tools.

If you search for terms like 'java byte code obfuscation' you can probably find tools that claim to provide some level of scrambling of names and or functionality of JVM byte code.  I do not know how effective they are.

In general, making a contract with a party that has something to lose in the contract, or more important things to do than try to reverse engineer your code, is a more sure protection against reverse engineering than technical methods.

Comment: Compiled programs can be snooped into these days, and secure server side hosted apps are the way to go indeed. Thanks for the ideas Andy. The last paragraph, most importantly.